# Onclick simple JS menu. I need some advice

Tags: javascript, html

Hi there I am working on this simple tabbing solution for an onpage sub menu.  It works with 2 options "about-bio-txt" and "about-eb-txt".  When I tried to add a third option, I am having issues.  I have edited the text down to a few words, but the code is exactly the same.

```
<ul id="switch-menu">

  <li id="about-eb" class="on"><a href="#" onclick='$("#about-bio-txt").hide(); $("#about-3").hide(); $("#about-eb-txt").show(); return false;'>About Everyday Bright</a></li>
  <li id="about-bio"><a href="#" onclick='$("#about-eb-txt").hide(); $("#about-3").hide(); $("#about-bio-txt").show(); return false;'>Bio</a></li>
enter code here
  <li id="about-3"><a href="#" onclick='$("#about-eb-txt").hide(); $("#about-bio-txt").hide(); $("#about-3").show(); return false;'>About Three</a></li>
```

The content for the tabs is is just before this menu.

```
<div id="about-eb-txt">The Constitution</div>
<div id="about-bio-txt">Science is life</div>
<div id="about-3">I AM A TREE</div>
```

I was wandering if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong and if I am able to add MORE tabs if I need to.

Comment: Just a guess, but if you were to follow the pattern then you would have `<li id="about-me">` and `<div id="about-me-txt">`. (Using `me` instead of `3` in case your script prefers letters.) In any case, you can't have two elements with the same `id`, which you do in your html with `id=about-3`.

Comment: What are the issues that you are having?

Comment: This is a link to what I am working on.  Sorry, I should have posted it.


http://jclead.net/t/cl/everyday/store-2/career-crossroads/


The 3rd menu, I changed the title of, but its still keeping the same title as another li tag.   

The 3rd menu option disappears when you click on either of the first 2 tabs, but the content for the 3rd tab is showing on all 3 tabs.  

I essentially wanted to add a tabs and just mimic what was there and working already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your menu div ID for the 3rd option and associated tab container have been given the same ID - #about-3

The below should work. Also reduced the JS required from multiple object targets for the same hide request...

```
<li id="about-eb" class="on"><a href="#" onclick='$("#about-bio-txt, #about-3-txt").hide(); $("#about-eb-txt").show(); return false;'>About Everyday Bright</a></li>
<li id="about-bio"><a href="#" onclick='$("#about-eb-txt, #about-3-txt").hide(); $("#about-bio-txt").show(); return false;'>Bio</a></li>
<li id="about-3"><a href="#" onclick='$("#about-eb-txt, #about-bio-txt").hide(); $("#about-3").show(); return false;'>About Three</a></li>


<div id="about-eb-txt">The Constitution</div>
<div id="about-bio-txt">Science is life</div>
<div id="about-3-txt">I AM A TREE</div>
```